# Position fixed element overlays scrollbar in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

http://jsfiddle.net/qJKKC/2/

I've got a nav peeking out from the right-hand side of the screen. As it does, I use an `:after` CSS generated element to darken the main content. In other browsers, this works fine, but in IE10 the generated element overlays the scrollbar. In the above fiddle, push the bottom of the window up until a scrollbar is present, then click on the text and you'll see what I mean.

I'm using the `.window` element to prevent horizontal scrolling to the nav.

How can I prevent this element overlaying the scrollbar, or otherwise achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem as I don't have IE10 but as a guess you could try adding a high positive number to the `z-index` on the nav element:

```
.nav {
z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: The nav element is above the 'darkening' element, it's the scrollbar for the .window element that is covered.